# C Program that counts Words and Lines in Standard input

Tags: c

I am new to C programming and I am currently trying to teach myself how to create a C program that can count words and lines in the input stream and print the two totals to the standard output.

What I am actually trying to do is to have the program count the number of lines and count the number of words depending on the definition of a word in which I feel that I am off.

I want the words to exclude blanks, tabs, newlines, hyphens, or colons. While having the program output the results (words and lines) as decimals.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int iochar;
    int words;
    int lines;

    printf("Enter something here:\n\n");

    while ((iochar = getchar ()) !=EOF)
    {
        if((iochar == ' ') || (iochar == '\t') || (iochar == '\n'))

        putchar(iochar);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Am I totally off on this program?

Comment: When you say it is "not working", what are you expecting this program to do, and how does it not meet your expectations? (I see it won't compile, but I'm not sure whether that is the problem you're seeing or whether the missing `}` is simply an omission when posting to SO.)

Answer (score 1):

If your question is how to fix the compile error, that's simple.  Add one more closing brace at the end.

But your program will still do only one pass through the loop and will print only one character if and only if the user types a space, tab or newline.  No matter what the user types, the program will then terminate.   I doubt that's what you wanted.

I suspect this is what you intended:

```
while ((iochar = getchar ()) !=EOF)
{
    if((iochar == ' ') || (iochar == '\t') || (iochar == '\n'))
    {
        putchar(iochar);
    }
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction, do you think that this program might read data from standard input one character as a time and output the results to standard output. What i am actually trying to do it is have the program count the number of lines and count the number of words depending on the definition of a word in which i feel that i am off. I want the words to not include blanks, tabs, newlines, hyphens, or colons.

Comment: I recommend that you make another attempt at it with the corrections I offered and then re-post your question beginning with the "What I am actually trying to do" part.  That's the first time you've clearly explained what your goal is.

Answer (score 0):

After your "I am trying to have thee numbers be right justified in an 8-column field ..." I cannot understand what you are trying to say :(

```
int words = 0;
int lines = 0;
char buffer[1024];
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin))
{
    lines++;
    if(buffer[0] == '\n')
        continue;
    char *tmp = buffer-1;
    while(tmp = strchr(tmp+1, ' '))
        words++;
    words++; /* count last word before \0*/
}

printf("lines: %d, words: %d\n", lines, words);
```

is that what you need/want?

Comment: What does the "fgets" do, when i tried to see if this would work with what i am trying to do it came back as errors. Sory for the confusion as far as me stating "I am trying to have the numbers be right justified in an 8-column field." What i am pretty much trying to have done is to have the program counts words and line in standard input and have it count words and lines and have it output it in standard output.

Comment: 15        156                                                         is the kind of output i would like to have. pretty much where the 15 is the number of lines and the 156 is the words. Which i would like the program count the number of words and lines in the input stream and print these two numbers on the standard output.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is:

> Test.c:20:1: error: expected declaration or statement at end of input

It does not compile because you are missing a `}`.

Had you properly indented your code, like so, you would have found your mistake:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

   int iochar;
   int words;
   int lines;

    printf("Enter something here:\n\n");

    while ((iochar = getchar ()) !=EOF)
    {
       if((iochar==' ')||(iochar=='\t')||(iochar=='\n'))
       {
       putchar(iochar);
       iochar = getchar();
       }
       return 0;

    }
```

Yet another example of the importance of readability :)

Comment: How does using two different styles of bracing improve readability?  And how does not indenting the statements within the if clause qualify as proper indentation?  And no matter how you indent it, it's still not going to work.  The logic is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: @CareyGregory Take a look at the original post; the code in the main method is not indented. He also says that his error is that it doesn't compile. Well, his compilation error is the lack of a `}`. As to the logic error, you are correct. So I'll +1 your post.