# How do I count words and lines in an input stream?

Tags: c, stream, counting

I am new to C programming and I am currently trying to teach myself how to create a C program that can count words and lines in the input stream and print the two totals to the standard output.

What I am trying to do is to have the program count the number of lines and count the number of words in an input stream. I would like to have the program include words but to exclude blanks, tabs, newlines, hyphens, or colons. While having the program output the results (words and lines) as decimals.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int iochar;
int words;
int lines;

printf("Enter something here:\n\n");

while ((iochar = getchar ()) !=EOF)
    {
    if((iochar == ' ') || (iochar == '\t') || (iochar == '\n'))

    putchar(iochar);
    }

return 0;
}
```

I would like to have the program output decimal of the value of words and lines it counted in standard output. This does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: i remember seeing this already...

Comment: you also have no counting code. so it obviously will not print out counts. Also it only prints out whitespace characters so you will not see it working.

Comment: FILE* f = popen("/usr/bin/wc", "w"); while(c = getchar()) fprintf(f, "%c", c);

Comment: yes i had already posted this before but i was ask to re-post it to make it more clear on what i am trying to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C Program that counts Words and Lines in Standard input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12591664/c-program-that-counts-words-and-lines-in-standard-input)

Answer (score 1):

You have to increment the value of `lines` when the read value is `\n`. To count the number of words, you can see these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837800/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-count-lines-and-words-in-a-text-file-in-ansi-c).

You can also use `wc` program (UNIX)...

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i am using, Unix system.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a `switch` statement instead of an `if`, and add some counting logic:

```
int wordLen = 0;
while (...) {
    switch(iochar) {
    case '\n':
        lines++; // no "break" here is intentional
    case '\t':
    case ' ':
        words += (wordLen != 0);
        wordLen = 0;
        break;
    default:
        wordLen++;
        break;
    }
}
if (wordLen) words++;
```

There is a K&R chapter that goes through this exercise in details, see section *1.5.4 Word Counting*.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read up on the standard library functions [`isspace`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/isspace.html) and [`ispunct`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/ispunct.html); that's easier than doing explicit tests against various character values (and it takes locale into account).

You'll need to initialize `words` and `lines` to 0 and then update them as you check your inputs:

```
if (isspace(iochar) || ispunct(iochar) || iochar == EOF)
{
  if (previous_character_was_not_space_or_punctuation)  // you'll have to figure
  {                                                     // out how to keep track 
    words++;                                            // of that on your own
  }

  if (iochar == '\n')
  {
    lines++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As AK4749 mentioned, you do not have any counting code.

Also in the if statement, you only output the character to stdout if it is space, tab or new line. I believe you want the opposite.

I would try something like the following:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    int iochar, words,lines;
    words=0;
    lines=0;


    printf("Enter something here:\n\n");

    while ((iochar = getchar ()) !=EOF)
    {
        if((iochar == ' ') || (iochar=='\t')) 
            words++;
        else if (iochar == '\n')
            lines++;
        else
        {
            putchar(iochar);
        }
    }
    printf("Lines: %d, Words: %d", lines, words);
    return 0;
}
```

I have not tried to compile this but it should not be too far from ok.

Hope it helps, 
Lefteris

Comment: Thanks, i tried to compile the program but it seems that it might have come back with some error:

Comment: line 10: syntax error before or at: int
"program.c", line 27: warning: function prototype parameters must have types
"program.c", line 27: warning: old-style declaration or incorrect type for: printf
"program.c", line 27: warning: identifier redeclared: printf
        current : function() returning int
        previous: function(pointer to const char, ...) returning int : "/usr/include/iso/stdio_iso.h", line 206
"program.c", line 28: syntax error before or at: return
"program.c", line 28: warning: syntax error:  empty declaration

Comment: Hello, I have updated the code block. I also included the following comment in the update: initializing `words` means that we cannot declare another variable (in C as opposed to C++ you can only declare variables in the beginning of the function or block). Also the test for new line was incorrect (it was reverse). I have updated the code and tried compiling it without problems.